# Unable to get data using requests.get while it works with curl

Tags: python-3.x, curl, url, ietf-restconf

Im trying to get response using RESTCONF. When i use CURL as:

> curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/yang-data+json" -H "Content-Type: application/yang-data+json" -k https://user:pass@IP/api/data/switch:opm/port={1,2}

I get output perfectly as

> "switch:port": {
> "port-id": 1,
> "wavelength": "0000.0",
> "offset": "0.0",
> "averaging-time": 4   } } {   "switch:port": {
> "port-id": 2,
> "wavelength": "0000.0",
> "offset": "0.0",
> "averaging-time": 0   } }

But when i use requests.get in python as:

```
url ="""https://IP/api/data/switch:opm/port={1,2}"""
response  = requests.get(url,headers=self.header,auth =(self.username1,self.password1),verify=False)
```

I get response 404.
I tried port=1 and it works fine in python too. Facing issues when i use port={1,2}.

Comment: What is the purpose of those curly braces (`{`, `}`) in that resource identifier? They need to be percent encoded if `port` is a list entry with `{1,2}` as a key value.

Comment: @predi Tried it, Still not working. Is there any way I can know what URL curl is using after I run the command?

Comment: I'm not proficient enough in curl to answer that - perhaps its man pages can help. I do however know RESTCONF and I do not think retrieval of more than one list entry in a single query is an intended use case - you can only retrieve a single list entry or all the entries of the list at once (by not specifying any keys). The output you got using curl appears to be incorrect - if more than one list entries are retrieved, a server must respond with a JSON array. That output is just two concatenated JSON objects.

Comment: Yeah, [curl man pages](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html) mention the curly brace notation right off the bat: `You can specify multiple URLs or parts of URLs by writing part sets within braces and quoting the URL`. That explains the output you got.

Comment: Perhaps adding the `-v` parameter to your curl command will make it more obvious that two consecutive requests are being made by it.

Comment: @predi. You are right. Curl is making two different requests.  Thank you for your help. It cleared my doubt.